# Is surjectivity equivalent to the existence of a right inverse?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, linear-transformations, banach-spaces, dual-spaces

My question is : is the following reasoning correct ?

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two Banach spaces and let $T:X\rightarrow Y$ a bounded
surjective operator. Then $T^{\ast }$ $:Y^{\ast }\rightarrow X^{\ast }$ is a
bounded below operator and hence it has a left inverse $R^{\ast }$ $:Y^{\ast
}\rightarrow X^{\ast }$, that is $R^{\ast }T^{\ast }=Id_{Y^{\ast }}$ then $%
TR=Id_{X}$ and hence $T$ has a right inverse.

Or must $X$ and $Y$ be reflexive to do like ?

Thank you !

Comment: If an operator is bounded below, then it doesn't necessarily have a left inverse. This is where your argument breaks down.